# Using pandas.date_range() to generate multiple datetimes, two dates per week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals

I'm using `pd.date_range(start_date,  end_date, freq='W-MON')` to generate weekly frequency datetimes every Monday between `start_date=2017-01-01` and  `end_date=2017-12-31`, which means approximately 4 datetimes are generated per month. How to generate 8 datetimes per month instead i.e. generate 2 datetimes per week but on different days in a week, say Monday and any other day apart from Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: @NickilMaveli: I've updated the question.

Comment: I guess you could generate another set of dates with a different frequency value, say `'W-TUE'`the same way you did before and append that to the first one. You could even sort these thereafter.

Comment: @NickilMaveli please post that as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are at-least two ways of achieving this:

1) You can probably choose a weekly frequency corresponding to a different day of the week and take [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of them which sorts the indices nicely and appends them.

```
start_date = "2017-01-01"
end_date = "2017-12-31"

d1 = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="W-MON")
d2 = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="W-TUE")

d1.union(d2)
```

---

2) A simpler way would be to create an offset corresponding to an extra `Day`. Followed by the same `union` operation.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day

d1.union(d1 + Day(1))
```

Both approaches produce:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-09', '2017-01-10',
               '2017-01-16', '2017-01-17', '2017-01-23', '2017-01-24',
               '2017-01-30', '2017-01-31',
               ...
               '2017-11-27', '2017-11-28', '2017-12-04', '2017-12-05',
               '2017-12-11', '2017-12-12', '2017-12-18', '2017-12-19',
               '2017-12-25', '2017-12-26'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=104, freq=None)
```